# Finding Lowest Common Multiple using numpy (for more than two inputs)

Tags: python, numpy, lcm

So I would like to find the lowest common multiple of 4 or more numbers in python. Now I understand that in numpy, you can just use np.lcm but the function is only restricted to two inputs.

```
import numpy as np
result = np.lcm(12, 8) # calculating the lcm of 12 and 8
print(result)

24
```

The question is how do I find the lcm of 3 or more integers using the same lcm function in numpy

Comment: Why do you want to use NumPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use `np.lcm.reduce()`, and pass it an array of numbers:

```
>>> np.lcm.reduce([1, 2, 3, 4])
12
```

Comment: how does reduce work in this sense ?

Comment: It basically loops over each value of the array, calling `np.lcm()` with the current value of the array, the value returned from the last call of that function. So it basically ends up as `np.lcm(np.lcm(np.lcm(np.lcm(1, 1), 2), 3), 4)`

Comment: @richardec Are you sure it doesn't start with `np.lcm(1, 2)`?

Comment: Yes, you're right @nocomment, apologies.

Comment: so Its basically `np.lcm(np.lcm(np.lcm(np.lcm(1, 2), 3), 4)` right ?

Comment: Exactly @DaddySinged.

Comment: I wasn't sure, btw. I just figured that if it does start with a neutral element, `np.lcm.reduce([])` would give me that instead of an error. Now I'm just still wondering why @DaddySinged doesn't want to use `math.lcm`...

Comment: math.lcm does not exist though ? This is all the function that exist in the math module
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/modules/math

Comment: @DaddySinged https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm

Comment: @DaddySinged That page doesn't even list `math.gcd`, which was introduced in Python 3.5, over six years ago. Pretty bad. Why would you look at anything other than the official documentation?

Comment: interestingly this gives the an incorrect answer for me. I'm using the numbers [20659, 20093, 14999, 17263, 22357, 16697] the answer should be 22103062509257 but numpy is saying its 1227249567